# iOS9 floating button over tableview doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a floating button that appears at the top of a tableview which allows users to quickly get back to the top. It works on all versions of iOS except for iOS9 for some reason. The button appears when the user begins to scroll upwards. When I click on it, it just stops the tableview from scrolling and does not execute the button's action. If the tableview is not scrolling, then the button works. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.scrollToTopButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   self.scrollToTopButton.alpha = 0.0f;
   self.scrollToTopButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 37);
   self.scrollToTopButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f];
   self.scrollToTopButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   self.scrollToTopButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [self.scrollToTopButton setTitle:@"Scroll To Top" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   self.scrollToTopButton.backgroundColor = golfGamutGreen;
   [self.scrollToTopButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollToTop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   [self.tableView addSubview:self.scrollToTopButton];
   [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:self.scrollToTopButton];
}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
 }

 -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [UIButton animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0     options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    [self.scrollToTopButton setAlpha:0.0f];
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
 }];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

  self.scrollToTopButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 37);
  [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:self.scrollToTopButton];
  if (lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 1000 && isScrollingToTop == NO) {
      [UIButton animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
     [self.scrollToTopButton setAlpha:0.9f];
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
 }
 else  {
     [UIButton animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
     [self.scrollToTopButton setAlpha:0.0f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   }];
 }
  if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
     [UIButton animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
     [self.scrollToTopButton setAlpha:0.0f];
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   }];
     isScrollingToTop = NO;
   }
 }

  - (void)scrollToTop {
   NSLog(@"Scroll To Top");
   //[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
     [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
     isScrollingToTop = YES;
 }
```

Comment: This is a nonstandard design idiom for iOS. Just say self.tableView.scrollsToTop = YES; then tap the status bar.